# forkify project works smoothly on local host but not working after deployment using github to netlify

Tags: javascript, github, netlify

forkify project works smoothly on local host but not working after deployment using GitHub to netlify and shows an error  index.82a04af9.js:25 Uncaught ReferenceError: Fraction is not defined
at index.82a04af9.js:25:86
(anonymous) @ index.82a04af9.js:25

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Sd8.png)

how can i solve this ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.